# django get value from template.html

Tags: python, mysql, django

I really need help...i ve been asking a lot of times for help and looked on google and i haven't found anything....

I want when the I click on the Table name i want to get the ID and number and obtain the details about the that table.

table_base.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<br>
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> {{ table_name }} List</h1>
    {% if list_tables %}
    <table>
    <thead>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </thead>
        {% for list in list_tables %}
        <tr>
            <td><pre>{{ list.id }}</pre></td>
            <td><pre><a class="btn-link" href="{% url 'tables:details' list.id %}">{{ list.name }}</a></pre></td>
            <td> <pre>{{ list.date }}</pre></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
        {% else %}
        <p> No Records Found</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def table_base(request):
    table_name = Crawledtables._meta.db_table
    list_tables = Crawledtables.objects.order_by('id')
    return render(request, 'tables/table_base.html', {'table_name': table_name,
                                                      'list_tables': list_tables})


class AboutDetail(DetailView):
    model = Crawledtables
    pk_url_kwarg = 'table_id'
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AboutDetail, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        if 'table_id' not in self.kwargs:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=1)
        else:
            return Crawledtables.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['table_id'])



class Details(ListView):
    model = AllTables
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'details'
    paginate_by = 15
    queryset = AllTables.objects.all()
```

tables/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.table_base, name='tables'),
    url(r'^(?P<table_id>\d+)$', views.AboutDetail.as_view(), name='id-details'),
    url(r'^(?P<table_id>\d+)/details$', views.Details.as_view(), name='details'),]
```

Basically i want to get the value of the table_id and make a new function in views where i get the table info based on what table_id i have...
If i have table_id 2 i want to the data of table_name2...
if i have table_id 3 i want to the data of table_name3...and so on. 
I want this data to list it on a new template that i will create.

Something like this for the views.py:

I will get the table_id = 2 and then i use table_id to get the table name that has that id. When i get the table name..i will put it in the models.py in db_table to get that specific table details.

```
def details(request, table_id):
     tbl_name = Crawledtables.objects.get(id=table_id)
     AllTables._meta.db_table = tbl_name

     query = AllTables.objects.order_by('id')
     tbl_query = {'t_details': query}
     return render(request, 'tables/table_list.html', context=tbl_query)
```

Thank you in advance

***UPDATE:***

I almost figure it out...but i still missing 1 more thing.

views.py

```
class Details(ListView):
    AllTables._meta.db_table = 'table_name_1'
    # AllTables._meta.db_table = 'table_name_2'
    # AllTables._meta.db_table = 'table_name_3'

    model = AllTables
    template_name = 'tables/table_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'details'
    paginate_by = 15
    queryset = AllTables.objects.all()
```

I need to switch between those 3 tables based on the table_id that i get from 
views.AboutDetail or the table_base.html when the user clicks on the table_name

Something like this:

```
class Details(ListView):
    if AboutDetail.pk_url_kwarg == 1:
         AllTables._meta.db_table = 'table_name_1'
    if AboutDetail.pk_url_kwarg == 2:
         AllTables._meta.db_table = 'table_name_2'
    if AboutDetail.pk_url_kwarg == 3:
         AllTables._meta.db_table = 'table_name_3'
    else:
         pass
```

Comment: [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: whats that for?